# arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory

Tags: raspbian-jessie, alsa

I am trying to install Jasper (Jasper is an open source platform for developing always-on, voice-controlled applications) on Raspberry Pi 2 (Jessie). I have a mic to give the commands, but it does not seem to be working. 
As per the documentation

1. Plug in your USB microphone. Let’s open up an ALSA configuration file in vim: `sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. Change the following line: `options snd-usb-audio index=-2`, to this: `options snd-usb-audio index=0`
3. Back in the shell, run: `sudo alsa force-reload` (Does not work, says "could not find alsa")
4. Next, test that recording works (you may need to restart your Pi) by recording some audio with the following command: `arecord temp.wav` (throws error "arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory")

I have looked at one of the solutions on [this site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40831/how-do-i-configure-my-sound-for-jasper-on-raspbian-jessie/40832), but it did not work for me.

The Jasper instructions are: [Manual Installation](http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation/)

mic: Kinobo USB Microphone

speaker: Logitech S150 USB Speakers with Digital Sound

Comment: The Jasper instructions are outdated and partially wrong (`index` works only if used with all drivers); please use the `slots` method instead, and file a bug with Jasper.

Comment: As per the instructions mentioned I did try the slot # This sets the index value of the cards but doesn't reorder.
options snd_usb_audio index=0
options snd_bcm2835 index=1

# Does the reordering.
options snd slots=snd-usb-audio,snd-bcm2835
Should I comment 
options snd_usb_audio index=0
options snd_bcm2835 index=1

Comment: The `index` options are no longer needed.

Comment: That did not help. I still get the same error. But if I change the command from arecord test.wav to sudo arecord test.wav. It starts the recording. I tried sudo usermod -a -G audio <accountname>, it still did not work. Any idea.

Comment: What are the permissions on the device files in `/dev/snd/`? Is your user in the audio group?

Comment: @CL.
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root       220 Jan 14 20:54 snd
I added the user to audio group
uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(pi) groups=1000(pi),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),101(input),108(netdev),997(gpio),998(i2c),999(spi)

Comment: The permissions of the `snd` directory itself do not matter; look at the files inside.

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a solution](https://scribles.net/voice-recording-on-raspberry-pi/) you might find helpful:

`arecord -D hw:2,0 -d 5 -f cd test.wav -c 1`

D option specifies recording device. Since this specific test mic is on “card 2”, “device 0”, the value is “hw:2,0” here. This command creates “test.wav” as a 5-second, CD-quality wave file. Since it’s a mono mic, specify “1” as the number of channels with “-c” option.

To play, simply secure-copy the "test.wav" to download the file on to whatever device is logged-in to the Raspberry Pi (in my case, it's a MacBook).  Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 for explaining all the of the options so well. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: Thank you- if interested, check-out my blog-post detailing the above in addition to other helpful instructions: https://www.alexanderjsingleton.com/hack-to-spy-building-a-raspberry-spy-pi/

Answer (score 3):

Use arecord -Dhw:cardID:deviceID test.wav

For MIC
You can find the card ID and device ID of kinobo USB from arecord -l

For Play
The aplay -l ---> will display Card Id and Device ID

$ aplay -Dhw:CardID:DeviceID test.wav

Note:

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo arecord --format=S16_LE --duration=5 --rate=16000--file-type=raw out.raw
```

To play, you will then need to run this:

```
aplay --format=S16_LE --rate=16000 out.raw
```

Answer (score -1):

Installing PulseAudio could be so helpful on Linux systems.
From a [Linux.com](https://www.linux.com/news/why-you-should-care-about-pulseaudio-and-how-start-doing-it) Article

> PulseAudio could account for 90% of the audio needs of a regular Linux session. To install use :`$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`

**Final thoughts** Your ALSA may have issues. Just try resetting it:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils reset
```

For more information alsa use and reset, these was [my source](http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/01/sound-configuration-on-raspberry-pi-with-alsa/)

Comment: Your answer, while it may be correct, is somewhat terse. Could you edit your answer, and expand why the "issues" that you refer to occur, and why the reset is necessary?