# Unable to configure microphone and speaker using arecord

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to configure a microphone and speaker but it is not working at all. The error message I get is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -d 10 test.wav
arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

I've tried all of the possible ways to configure it.

Comment: What microphone are you using and how is it connected to the RPi?

Comment: Maybe this will help you - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41077/arecord-main722-audio-open-error-no-such-file-or-directory